# Huge PDF size (on real device) created by ios App Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, uiscrollview, simulator

Currently in my ios app, I am creating a pdf from a UIScrollView. When the pdf is created on the simulator, the file size is about 1.5 mo. But when I do it on a real device (an iPad), the file is about 75 mo...

Do someone know why I get this problem?

**Edit 1**

The problem seem to appear on every device (simulator or real) on iOS >= 10.3. But on iOS = 8.3, no problem for the pdf size...

**Edit 2**

I found that the problem might be related to UILabel. When I comment the UILabel from being added to the scrollview, the pdf size is normal. When I uncomment the UILabel, the pdf size get huge...

Here's my code for creating the PDF:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *directroyPath = nil;
directroyPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"PDF"];
NSString *filePath = [directroyPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.pdf"];



NSError *error;
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {

} else {
  [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:directroyPath
                          withIntermediateDirectories:NO
                                           attributes:nil
                                                error:&error];

}

CGContextRef pdfContext = [self createPDFContext:myScrollView.bounds path:(CFStringRef)filePath];

CGFloat height = 1056;

for (int i = 0 ; i< nbPage ; i++) {
  CGContextBeginPage (pdfContext,nil);

  //turn PDF upsidedown
  CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
  transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, (i+1) * height);
  transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, 1.0, -1.0);
  CGContextConcatCTM(pdfContext, transform);

  //Draw view into PDF
  [myScrollView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];
  CGContextEndPage (pdfContext);
  [myScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, (i+1) * height) animated:NO];
}
CGContextRelease (pdfContext);

unsigned long long fileSize = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:filePath error:nil] fileSize];
NSLog(@"FileSize: %llu", fileSize);

}
```

Thank you,